# Why do physicist tend to approximate the constant change in temperature in terms of a sine function?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

I have gained interest on how physicists try to approximate the constant change in temperature to the surroundings in terms of a sine function. I have made a study about Newton’s law of cooling with fluctuations in temperature considering that the fluctuation is sinusoidal but I have got no clue why the change in temperature would be sinusoidal. Please let me know what you think?

Comment: What would you personally use?

Comment: What do you mean by "constant change" here? A sin wave does not describe a constant rate of change.

Comment: @nasu I am just guessing but I think his question is why (co)sinusoids are used for linear systems.

Comment: I just asked what does he mean by that expression.  Not what is the context of his question.

Comment: @hyportnex, yes that is what I probably mean. In the sense that I have drawn the normal function for newton’s law of cooling thus I am comparing it to the function with the added sin part. Is there a reason for including the sine part? Like I want to understand the scientific context behind it?

Comment: @nasu, does that make sense?

Comment: Well,  you did not answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtually nothing in reality follows a precise (co)sine function, but a lot of things have an oscillating / fluctuating behavior and the sine function just ... looks like it!
There are however several other reasons physicists like (co)sine functions in general. Here's some [I will talk about the sine, the cosine works too though]:

**1. they are differentiable**

It is better, of course, to have a *continuous* and *differentiable* function in your theory, it makes things easier. Of course because
${d sin(x) \over dx} = cos(x)$ is a very well known rule, physicists will tend to take advantage of it. Also, as you see, the derivative of a sine is a cosine i.e. a function which looks the same but is simply shifted. This also makes things easier!

**2. they are a general solution for oscillating systems**

If you have anything that oscillates not too fast (a simple pendulum, a spring system, a fluctuation in your signal) you can most times approximate it as a harmonic motion i.e. something that follows the equation $$\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}=-\alpha y$$
The general solution for this equation is.. a sine with a phase and amplitude (the frequency $\omega$ can be extracted from $\alpha$)!
$$y(t)=A sin(\omega t+\phi)$$

**2a. they are periodic**

Because $sin(x+2\pi)=sin(x)$ you can model a generic periodic phaenomena as a sine.

**3. because of Fourier analysis**

There is a crazy interesting result, called *Fouerier series* that says that almost *any* periodic function (and this can also be extended to non periodic ones) can be writte as a sum of sines and cosines. So, a lot of times, if you have a generic problem, and you can solve it in the ideal case in which the solution is a sine, then you can sum such solutions and end up with a general solution to your problem. This is very very powerful! The details are complicated but you can easily google some first details about it if you are interestng by simply typing "Fourier series"

I would say these are the main reasons to use sines in physics in general. Regarding your specific problem, I don't know the details of it but chances are the source you are quoting uses a sine either because the temperature fluctuation is periodic or because it will attempt to solve the problem with a Fourier series.